# "Given Path Format Is Not Supported"... Can you help me?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

So, I made a speech recognizer and it was working fine, I'm not sure why is it giving me this error right now. Any ideas?

```
String res = e.Result.Text;

string yol = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            string settings = ("@" + yol + "\\" + "settings" + "\\");


            if (res == "Hi Bot")
            {
              pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(settings + "mybot.png"); -->That's where i get the error
              say(greetings_random());
            }
```

Comment: Check the "Copy to Output Directory" setting for mybot.png. (Right click mybot.png, select properties, and see if Copy to Output Directory does not have the value "Do not copy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string yol = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string settings = ("@" + yol + "\\" + "settings" + "\\");
```

This means that `settings` has the value `"@C:\Path\To\Executable\settings\"`.

That's probably not what you want -- I'm not sure what the `@` is trying to achieve, but it's not valid at the beginning of a path like that.

For future, debugging this code and inspecting the `settings` variable would quickly have shown the problem.

---

That said, it's recommended to use [`Path.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=netcore-3.1) (.NET Core 2.1+) or [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1) instead of string concatenation to create paths like this.

Comment: Oh, I wanted something like @"C:\Path\To\Executable\settings\mybot.png"... How do I do it then?

Comment: @Dafi You're probably confused by the syntax for a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals). This is syntax for *declaring* the string -- if you use a `@` before the opening `"` it just means that the string has different rules for which characters should be escaped. For example, you could write `yol + @"\settings\"` instead of `yol + "\\settings\\"`

Comment: I didn't know that. Yes, that solved my problem. Thank you for your help :)